# How to widen helm buffer names in `helm-buffers-list`?

Tags: helm

One of the things I find annoying in `emacs-helm` is the size of the column showing buffer names in `helm-buffers-list`. I have searched the documentation and couldn't find how to customize the width of this column.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Related: [How to truncate buffer information in helm list](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/490/how-to-truncate-buffer-information-in-helm-list)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should customize `helm-buffer-max-length` to an appropriate number. Default I believe is 20. If set to `nil`, helm will use the longest buffer name. You can access the customization setup by `M-x customize-variable helm-buffer-max-length`.