# How to truncate buffer information in helm list

Tags: helm

When I have a lot of buffers open and I use `helm-mini` to look through them, I notice that deeply-nested or tramp buffers take up too much horizontal space, causing them to wrap around, like this:

[image: buffer-wraparound]

How can I get helm to truncate these lines so they don't wrap around? Toggling `truncate-lines` when the helm buffer is open doesn't take effect.

Comment: Related: [How to widen helm buffer names in `helm-buffers-list`?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-widen-helm-buffer-names-in-helm-buffers-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant setting is `helm-buffers-truncate-lines` which truncates lines when non-nil. You can use `M-x customize-variable helm-buffers-truncate-lines` to toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

As for now. You can use:

- `C-c >` ([helm-toggle-truncate-line](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/a1791980f9ddca1989c65a67e6997bdde481dc27/helm.el#L236)) to truncate lines
- and `C-]` ([helm-ff-run-toggle-basename](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/f0f174138f6f3198a6b970fd29e7caa94236e3bc/helm-types.el#L43)) to toggle the list to the basename only

Answer (score 0):

as of now, it is still bound to <kbd>C-]</kbd> however the name of the function has been changed to `helm-toggle-buffers-details`. Another function that can be relevant is <kbd>C-c ></kbd> bound to `helm-toggle-truncate-line`. Another useful keybinding to adjust mini-buffer height is <kbd>C-}</kbd> or <kbd>C-{</kbd>.