# With helm-do-grep-ag, how can I helm-toggle-truncate-line to be able to see the whole line?

Tags: helm, ag

The results for helm-do-grep-ag disappears off screen

I've found this command

```
C-c > (helm-toggle-truncate-line) to truncate lines
```

This works;) , but I want to set it default.

Comment: Is [this link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/490/how-to-truncate-buffer-information-in-helm-list) helpful to you?