# View a whole file name or path in helm buffer

Tags: helm

I have long paths and filenames showing in my helm session and I want to quickly look at one and then go back to the normal view.  You can see my long paths and filenames below:

[image]

There are several related things that helm will do.  One of them is `C-] Toggle Details`, which gives toggles the view (starting with the above) shown below:

[image]

This only shows the full filenames though, and I also want to view the paths.

Another option in GUI emacs is to mouseover a result, but the path is so long that the hover text goes off the screen ('fml', nothing worse than thinking you've been saved by contextual hover menu/text, which then jumps off the screen anyway :D)

Finally, you can both [widen columns](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-widen-helm-buffer-names-in-helm-buffers-list) and [toggle truncated lines](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/490/how-to-truncate-buffer-information-in-helm-list).

That last one is important, because what I want to do, ideally, is toggle truncation for a selection of lines (or just the current line) with a key command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(helm-toggle-truncate-line)` is bound to `C-c >`.  I found this out by searching for `toggle` in the helm help page, accessed during a helm session with `C-h m`.

Answer (score 0):

Although slightly off topic, you may want to customize the `helm-xref-candidate-formatting-function` which provides the following choices:

- `helm-xref-format-candidate-short`. The default: only shows file base name.
- `helm-xref-format-candidate-full-path`.  Shows the full path of the file.
- `helm-xref-format-candidate-long`. Uses 2 lines per candidates: the file name with complete path in the first line, the second line is the string found in the file.

I find using `helm-xref-format-candidate-long` helps the most.